# What regex use to get network object from wpa_supplicant.conf?

Tags: android, regex, wpa-supplicant

I have file with the following structure:

```
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
update_config=1
device_name=P580_ROW
manufacturer=LENOVO
model_name=Lenovo 
model_number=Lenov
serial_number=hjhjh7
device_type=10-0050F204-5
os_version=01020300
config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button
p2p_no_group_iface=1

network={
    ssid="test1"
    psk="154695"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    sim_slot="-1"
    imsi="none"
    priority=1
}

network={
    ssid="SSID2"
    psk="test123456"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    sim_slot="-1"
    imsi="none"
    priority=19
}
```

I would like to ask, how can i get array list of the network objects (but can be JSON too) with accessible attributes using regex (Pattern and Matcher) or something simillar in Java?

I tried to find solution using the service 
http://txt2re.com/
But without luck to get objects with accessible attributes.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: You just need the `network`nodes or the other things too, like `config_methods ,model_name etc` ?

Comment: Just the network nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know the names of attributes and their count, you can make use of a regex based on `\G` operator:

```
String str = "<<YOUR_STRING>>";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<new>network=\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s*(?<key>\\w+)=\"?(?<value>[^\"\n]+)\"?");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
int count = 1;
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group("new") != null && matcher.group("new").length() > 0) {
        System.out.println("New Network: " + count);
        count += 1;
    }
    System.out.println(matcher.group("key") + ":\"" + matcher.group("value").trim() + "\"");
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rMLk3K)

The regex - `(?<new>network=\{|(?!^)\G)\s*(?<key>\w+)="?(?<value>[^"\n]+)"?` - matches:

- `(?<new>network=\{|(?!^)\G)` - `network={` or the end of the previous successful match (Group "new")
- `\s*` - optional whitespace
- `(?<key>\w+)` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols (Group "key")
- `="?` - literal `=` and an optional `"`
- `(?<value>[^"\n]+)` - 1 or more characters other than `"` and a newline (Group "value")
- `"?` - an optional `"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. Try it.

```
public class Test {

    private static final String REGEXP = "network=\\{\\n\\s*ssid=\"(?<ssid>.*)\"\\n\\s*psk=\"(?<psk>.*)\"\\n\\s*key_mgmt=(?<keymgmt>.*)\\n\\s*sim_slot=\"(?<simslot>.*)\"\\n\\s*imsi=\"(?<imsi>.*)\"\\n\\s*priority=(?<priority>.*)\\n}";
    private static final String DATA = "ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets\n" +
            "driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1\n" +
            "update_config=1\n" +
            "device_name=P580_ROW\n" +
            "manufacturer=LENOVO\n" +
            "model_name=Lenovo \n" +
            "model_number=Lenov\n" +
            "serial_number=hjhjh7\n" +
            "device_type=10-0050F204-5\n" +
            "os_version=01020300\n" +
            "config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button\n" +
            "p2p_no_group_iface=1\n" +
            "\n" +
            "network={\n" +
            "    ssid=\"test1\"\n" +
            "    psk=\"154695\"\n" +
            "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
            "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
            "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
            "    priority=1\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "\n" +
            "network={\n" +
            "    ssid=\"SSID2\"\n" +
            "    psk=\"test123456\"\n" +
            "    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK\n" +
            "    sim_slot=\"-1\"\n" +
            "    imsi=\"none\"\n" +
            "    priority=19\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXP);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(DATA);

        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("New network");
            System.out.println("-----------");
            System.out.println("SSID: "+matcher.group("ssid"));
            System.out.println("PSK: "+matcher.group("psk"));
            System.out.println("KEY MGMT: "+matcher.group("keymgmt"));
            System.out.println("SIM SLOT: "+matcher.group("simslot"));
            System.out.println("IMSI: "+matcher.group("imsi"));
            System.out.println("PRIORITY: "+matcher.group("priority"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am not efficient in RegExp. I think this method is dirty and there'd be better solutions than this.(WorkSpace: https://regex101.com/r/nA8fD1/1)