# Regex pattern in Android studio throws error : This named group syntax is not supported

Tags: java, android, regex, android-studio

i have the following regex pattern which is in the Android Studio throwing error This named group syntax is not supported.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<new>network=\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s*(?<key>\\w+)=\"?(?<value>[^\"\n]+)\"?");
```

But in the Ideone example is it working:

http://ideone.com/rMLk3K

I tried to solve it using the Regular Expression testing for Java

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

And there i got the following error:

```
Illegal repetition near index 17 "(?<new>network=\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s*(?<key>\\w+)=\"?(?<value>[^\"\n]+)\"?"
```

What can be wrong please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't see named group syntax mentioned in http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.  They're part of the non-Android Java runtime, but apparently Android just doesn't support it. Interestingly, the blurb says "The notation for the regular expressions is mostly a superset of those used in other Java language implementations"--they don't mention that there are things missing.  Anyway, that's a simple explanation for why your regex works in ideone but not in Android.

Comment: When you try regexplanet, don't put in double backslashes (except when you want your pattern to match a backslash).  In a Java string literal, you need a double-backslash in order to get a single backslash in your regex.  However, regexplanet will do this doubling for you (look at the box that says "as a Java string").  So if you give it doubled backslashes, you will end up with too many backslashes.

Comment: Could You please provide the right regex pattern? Regex is regarding to following  question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444452/what-regex-use-to-get-network-object-from-wpa-supplicant-conf

Comment: @redrom: What if you just use a key-value extraction regex [like this](http://ideone.com/rCHVBq)? No named groups, but no blocks. Or it can be done in 2 steps: getting the `{...}` blocks, and then apply the code above. Maybe [removing the name and using numbered groups](http://ideone.com/6YEt7u) can solve this.

Comment: Just get rid of `?<new>`.  The advantage of using this, in non-Android Java, is that you can put a name on your group and say things like `matcher.group("new")`.  But of course Android doesn't have a `group` method that takes a name, so you just have to use the group number (i.e. 1).  (In the code you point to, `matcher.group("new")` should result in a compile error.  Change those to `matcher.group(1)`.)

Comment: Just FYI: here is a [2-step approach](http://ideone.com/nBfbKi).

Comment: In Regular Expresion testing for java you can try it...
`(?<new>network=\{|(?!^)\G)\s*(?<key>\w+)=\"?(?<value>[^\"\n]+)\"?"`

Comment: Unfortunatelly no provided example is working for me on the Android.

Comment: @redom can you plz give it a try.. `Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("(?<new>network=\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s*(?<key>\\w+)=\\\"?(?<value>[^\\\"\\n]+)\\\"?\"");` ? it should give you 3 groups as i think, if you are using the same String as in example.

Comment: @sourabhbans The OP is using Android which doesn't support named capture groups like `(?<new>...)`, but you're giving him things to try that use capture groups.  They will not work for the OP.

Answer (score 8):

Android implements the `Pattern` class by writing a wrapper around ICU4C. Named capturing group is not supported by ICU4C prior to [ICU 55](http://site.icu-project.org/download/55).

At the time of answering (Sep 25th 2015), Android code base was [stuck at ICU 49.1.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/android-5.1.1_r18/icu4c/readme.html) on the latest tag at the time of writing (android-5.1.1_r18), so the regex doesn't compile. Since then, Android has [updated to ICU 55.1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/icu/+/marshmallow-release/icu4c/readme.html) in marshmallow-release branch, so the regex should compile from this version of Android. However, even if the regex compiles, without changes to the API on Java side, you won't be able to address the capturing groups by name.

For now, just write the regex without named groups and extract the matched content by group number as per normal:

```
Pattern.compile("(network=\\{|(?!^)\\G)\\s*(\\w+)=\"?([^\"\n]+)\"?");
```

You can access the groups `new`, `key`, `value` at groups numbered 1, 2, 3 respectively.

Comment: (To future readers: feel free to comment or just edit the post when Android starts to support named capturing groups).

Comment: Now can be pattern compiled but it returns  
New network
---------------
SSID: network={
PSK: ssid

It means without the value.

Comment: @redrom: I don't understand your comment, but whatever problem you have with the regex itself should belong on a new question (which should also include the test cases)

Answer (score 4):

I thought I should share a solution I found. There is a fantastic library available on Github written by Tony Trinh (tony19) that enables one to use named regex groups.

Taken from the project page:

"This lightweight library adds support for named capture groups in Java 5/6 (and on Android).

This is a fork of the named-regexp project from Google Code (currently inactive)."

https://github.com/tony19/named-regexp

I've just tested this on Android 4.1.1 and above, and so far it's working like a charm. I was pleasantly surprised to find that I could simply replace my imports for Matcher and Pattern with the classes from this library, and all of my existing regexes that still used numbered groups still worked.

I hop this helps.